# accessing old ubercart admin via an ip address ? how to?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

Hi recently upgraded a website from ubercart to another ecom platform

everything is fine with the new site after redelegating domain to new server and new site

issue is client needs to access the old ubercart site admin to fulfil the remaining orders..

i thought this would a simple case of changing the settings for admin from the domain to the old ip address

but no not that simple
seems nothing with ubercart ever is

i changed domain to old ip address here
/public_html/sites/default/files/settings.php

so now i can access site with ip address

but i cannot access admin?

if i go here...

ipaddress/user/

it revers back to domain.com/user.php, which of course is the new site and has no user.php file

i need to go to ipaddress/user.php
in order for client to sign in to old admin

any ideas would be appreciated, tried googling and cannot find how to change admin URL

thanks!

Comment: trying to track this down..

the URL appears in the form action on the /users/ page eg login screen
it appears hard coded but cannot find how to change this!

where would it be?

Comment: Drupal does not have user.php. you must be referring to something else

Comment: sorry not user.php just folder /user

Comment: anyone know? surely you can access admin via ip address ?!

Comment: Can you confirm if 'ipaddress' in question points to the previous Drupal installation?